# NSTimer grows data amount

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, nstimer, xcode-instruments

I'm watching my application in Instruments to lower the memory usage and memory growth. And I discovered one weird thing. When I start `NSTimer` with some interval (in my case 0.1 sec), in Instruments I can see that `CFArray (store-deque)` and `CFArray (mutable-variable)` still grows (about 200 Bytes per second). Is that OK? Or is it problem? *#Living* number is constant, *#Transitory* and *#Overall* grows. Also Overall memory is still bigger. And there are a lot of things in shadow for me. Like `Malloc 32 Bytes`, `Malloc 48 Bytes`...

Of course method called at timer "tick" is empty to be sure it's not me...

should I care about them or is it just system stuff...???
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but in case future readers stumble across this question like I just did, I'll point out that the numbers you need to worry about is "Live Bytes" and "# Living". The "Transitory" and "Overall" entries include items that have been created and subsequently destroyed.

For your reference, according to the [Allocations Instrument](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AnalysisTools/Reference/Instruments_User_Reference/AllocationsInstrument/AllocationsInstrument.html) documentation in the *Instruments User Reference:*

> **Live Bytes:**
>   The number of bytes that have been allocated, but not released.
>
> **# Living:**
>   The number of objects created and still on the heap.
>
> **# Transitory:**
>   The number of objects that were created and destroyed in the selected time range.
>
> **Overall Bytes:**
>   The total number of bytes of this type that have been allocated, including those that have been released.
>
> **# Overall:**
>   The total number of objects or memory blocks of this type that have been allocated, including those that have been released.
>
> **# Allocations (Net / Overall):**
>   A histogram of the current and total accounts.